# Translate TensorFlow to PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to translate the following code from tensorflow to pytorch:

```
decoder = GLOGenerator()
g_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001)
z_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)

def train_step(images, z_train):
    with tf.GradientTape() as g_tape, tf.GradientTape() as z_tape:
        result_images = decoder(z_train)
        g_loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(images, tf.squeeze(result_images))
    gradients_z = z_tape.gradient(g_loss, z_train)
    gradients_g = g_tape.gradient(g_loss, decoder.trainable_variables)

    z_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([gradients_z], [z_train]))
    g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_g, decoder.trainable_variables))
```

If it necessary, the calling function is here (if you need to understand what is the arguments of the train_step function):

```
z_vectors = np.random.normal(0, 1, (number_of_images, 10))
BATCH_SIZE = 32
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
images = x_train
number_of_images = images.shape[0]

def train(number_of_epoches):
    image_indexs = np.arange(images.shape[0])
    number_of_steps = images.shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE
    np.random.shuffle(image_indexs)
    for epoch in range(number_of_epoches):
        print("epoch: ", epoch)
        np.random.shuffle(image_indexs)
        for index in range(number_of_steps):
            z_for_train = tf.Variable(z_vectors[image_indexs[BATCH_SIZE * index: index * BATCH_SIZE + BATCH_SIZE]], dtype='float32')
            train_step(images[image_indexs[BATCH_SIZE * index: index * BATCH_SIZE + BATCH_SIZE]], z_for_train)
            z_train = z_for_train.numpy()
            z_train /= np.max(np.linalg.norm(z_vectors, axis=0, keepdims=True), 1)
            z_vectors[image_indexs[BATCH_SIZE * index: index * BATCH_SIZE + BATCH_SIZE]] = z_train
```

Comment: Please, be more specific in your question. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to translate it in Pytorch yet? If not, you should! In the event of you facing an error, you may ask for help here. It will be more appropriate this way, than to ask to get a piece of code translated for you. Good luck ;)